# Fastest method to calculate difference between two ARGB ints in Java?

Tags: java, colors

Given an int from a DataBuffer which has ARGB data packed in it with the masks

A = 0xFF000000
R = 0xFF0000
G = 0xFF00
B = 0xFF

I'm doing the following but wonder if there isn't a faster method in Java?

```
        DataBuffer db1 = img1.getData().getDataBuffer();
        DataBuffer db2 = img2.getData().getDataBuffer();

        int x, y;
        int totalDiff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; ++i) {
            x = db1.getElem(i);
            y = db2.getElem(i);

            totalDiff += Math.abs((x & 0xFF) - (y & 0xFF))
                       + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF00) >> 8) - ((y & 0xFF00) >> 8))
                       + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF0000) >> 16) - ((y & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ));
        }
```

Comment: What should be the difference of `0xFF000000` and `0x00FF0000`.

Comment: No difference, the code above ignores the A, extracts the individual R, G and B components from x and y and gets the difference, then add the absolute value of their difference. so of x is 0xFF010101 and y is 0xFF020202 then the difference would be 3

Comment: And the difference between 0xFF010104 and 0xFF020202 would be 0? Just checking if this is intentional.

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's just a heuristic I'm using but is quite the bottleneck. I suspect some trick to replace a call to Math.abs might be an improvement. Dumping the bytecode shows it's fairly short already.

Comment: Perhaps directly placing the code for abs(int) into the function but i would have though that hotspot would optimise this for me.

Comment: I must be stupid, but I don't see how the difference between `0xFF000000` and `0x00FF0000` should be 0 (I think it should be 255, because of the red channel), and how `0xFF010104 - 0xFF020202` should be 0. It seems to me that you would get `abs(-1)+abs(-1)+abs(2)` which is `1+1+2` which is 4.

Anyway, I think you can do the bit shifts after the subtraction and abs so you only have to do it once for each color.

Comment: @Johnny: working directly in the int[] instead of doing a get(i) can be up to 1000 times faster (measured on a Mac Mini).  1000 times.  So the first I'd do would be use a DataBuffer backed by an int[] and make sure to work directly in the array.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: And you surely adhered to all limitations for doing micro benchmarks (e.g. give the JIT the possibility to optimize the code) in java when coming up with that result? Sounds extremely unlikely.

Comment: @Jordi: you're right, I had a thinko there.

Comment: @Voo: of course I did... Statiscally measured.  The thing is: when you do a getRGB(x,y) or equivalent you go through a **LOT** of things, like applying the color model to the pixels etc.  When you do a array[x], retrieving a primitive, it's **fast**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need the speed up you might to check the type of `DataBuffer` and provide optimized code for the concrete type such that you save the calls to `getElem(i)`. This will speed up your code a little bit.

Something like this:

```
    DataBuffer db1 = img1.getData().getDataBuffer();
    DataBuffer db2 = img2.getData().getDataBuffer();

    int totalDiff = 0;
    int x, y;
    if (db1 instanceof DataBufferInt && db2 instanceof DataBufferInt) {
        int[] data1 = ((DataBufferInt) db1).getData();
        int[] data2 = ((DataBufferInt) db2).getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; ++i) {
            x = data1[i];
            y = data2[i];

            totalDiff += Math.abs((x & 0xFF) - (y & 0xFF))
                + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF00) >> 8) - ((y & 0xFF00) >> 8))
                + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF0000) >> 16) - ((y & 0xFF0000) >> 16));
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; ++i) {
            x = db1.getElem(i);
            y = db2.getElem(i);

            totalDiff += Math.abs((x & 0xFF) - (y & 0xFF))
                    + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF00) >> 8) - ((y & 0xFF00) >> 8))
                    + Math.abs(((x & 0xFF0000) >> 16) - ((y & 0xFF0000) >> 16));
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
Another idea that would bring you a MUCH higher speed up. If this is just a heuristic it might be enough to calculate the difference of a somewhat "downsampled" version of your images. Replace `++i` through `i+=10` and gain a speed up by factor 10. Of course if this makes sense depends on the types of your images.

**Edit:**
In one comment you mentioned it's a fitness function for a GA ... in this case it might be enough to grab 100 (or just 10?) random locations from your images and compare the pixels at that locations. The gained speed up will most probably outdo the loss in accuracy.

Comment: This doesn't give the same result: the r, g, b components are not compared separately

Comment: Ups ;). Right ... so we can save only the calls to "getElem(i)" using this approach ... this would only be an speed improvement by about 10% ... better than nothing.

Comment: I've tried sampling but it doesn't work. The variations are quite small sometimes and require all the pixels to be compared for best performance overall.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Arne.

You could also remove the shift rights

```
(x & 0xFF0000) >> 16) - ((y & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ).
```

You know that `abs(XX0000 - YY0000)` is only going to be in the range 0-255.

It would help if you could suggest what it is you are trying to determine?

That is, can the pixel information be store more conducively to what you are trying to acheive, for example as chrominance (YUV, YCrCb)?

Comment: `abs(XX0000 - YY0000)` is in the range `[-FF0000,FF0000]`. You still need to shift right, but you can do it after the `abs` operation: `abs((x & 0xFF0000) - (y & 0xFF0000)) >> 16`.

Comment: Well spotted. It's just a heuristic for a GA to calculate the difference between two images as a single number. 0 == no difference.

Comment: In that case you could 'break' out of the loop if totalDiff > 0

Comment: Unfortunately not. There are N images to be ranked. If you only sample you might incorrectly rank them.

Answer (score 0):

If calculating the sum of squares is acceptable for you, it is faster:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; ++i) {
        x = db1.getElem(i);
        y = db2.getElem(i);
        int dr = ((x & 0xFF0000) >> 16) - ((y & 0xFF0000) >> 16 );
        int dg = ((x & 0xFF00) >> 8) - ((y & 0xFF00) >> 8);
        int db = (x & 0xFF) - (y & 0xFF);
        totalDiff += dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db;
    }
```